# SQL: Query periods of time given date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a list of periods during a year, and they are the same every year. You can think of it as a Season. They have a startDate and a endDate.

Because there can be Seasons that leap each other, what I need to to is query all the matching Seasons given a date, **no matter what year**.

As an example:

Season1: from 1st of January to 10th of January
Season2: from 6th of January to 8th of January
Season3: from 11th of January to 20th of January

Given the date 7th of January, I'd need to retrieve the Season1 and Season2.

I've tried converting all dates to the same year, but It doesn't work when the Start Date of a season in "later" than  the End Date (for example, there's a period starting on November and ending of February).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edit, sample data:

```
StartDate   EndDate     SeasonId
2000-08-01  2000-08-31  4
2000-12-29  2000-01-02  3
2000-06-01  2000-07-30  3
2000-09-01  2000-09-30  3
2000-01-06  2000-01-08  3
2000-04-07  2000-04-17  3
2000-04-28  2000-05-01  3
2000-06-02  2000-06-05  3
2000-06-23  2000-06-25  3
2000-09-08  2000-09-11  3
2000-09-22  2000-09-25  3
2000-10-12  2000-10-15  3
2000-11-01  2000-11-05  3
2000-12-01  2000-12-10  3
2000-12-22  2000-12-26  3
2000-03-01  2000-05-31  2
2000-10-01  2000-10-31  2
2000-11-01  2000-02-28  1
```

And I'd need, for example, the season for the date `2000-02-08`, and retrieve `seasonId = 1`, or the date `2000-10-13`and retrive `seasonId = 3, seasonId = 2`

Comment: give sample data

Comment: Specify sample data and expected result

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does your data actually look like this? All from the same year and `2000-11-01  2000-02-28  1` is supposed to be from november to february?

Comment: Yes @dnoeth, but the thing here is that the year should not matter

Answer (score 1):

given tblSeason with columns Id, startdate, enddate and your date as @myDate you would query as

```
Select Id From tblSeason WHERE @myDate BETWEEN startdate AND enddate
```

would give list of Id's of the seasons that match.

if you can't work from that, please give more information in your examples as to the structure you are querying and the expected outcome.
*Edit to ignore the year part you could do similar to

```
    Declare @myDate datetime = '2016-10-13'

SELECT [StartDate]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[SeasonId]
  FROM [dbo].[Table_1]
  where DATEPART(dy, @myDate) >= DATEPART(dy,StartDate)
  AND (DATEPART(dy,@myDate) =< DATEPART(dy,EndDate) OR DATEPART(dy,StartDate) > DATEPART(dy,EndDate))
```

Comment: The thing here is that the year is irrelevant, for example, I've got a period going from November to February, and using your method the date 10th of December wouldn't work

Comment: yeah sorry I saw your edit after I had posted will edit answer

Answer (score 1):

You could query like this for the Season1:

```
select * from myTable where (month(myDate) = 1 and DAY(myDate) between 1 and 10)
```

If you have a season in more than one month, like start date January 20th, and finish date Febrery 10th, you could query this way:

```
select * from myTable where (month(myDate) = 1 and DAY(myDate) >= 20) or (month(myDate) = 2 and DAY(myDate) <= 10)
```

UPDATED WITH YOUR UPDATE

It is a little bit tricky, but it should work...

```
select *  from seasons_table
where cast(cast(day(myDate) as char) + '/' + cast(month(myDate) as char)  + '/' + '2000' as date) between
 cast(cast(day(StartDate) as char) + '/' + cast(month(StartDate) as char)  + '/' + '2000' as date) and
 cast(cast(day(EndDate) as char) + '/' + cast(month(EndDate) as char)  + '/' + '2000' as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in 2 'options': (the following SQL assumes you already got rid of the year in the table, and left only month-date format. )

```
 select ... from seasons s where 
    (s.startDate <= s.endDate and s.startDate <= @mydate and s.endDate >= @mydate) or 
    (s.startDate > s.endDate and s.startDate >= @mydate and s.endDate <= @mydate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you including the year in the table?  That seems strange.

In any case, you only care about the MM-DD format, so use `date_format()` to convert the values to strings:

```
select t.*
from t
where (start_date <= end_date and
       date_format(@date, '%m-%d') >= date_format(start_date, '%m-%d') and
       date_format(@date, '%m-%d') <= date_format(end_date, '%m-%d') 
      ) or
      (start_date > end_date and
       date_format(@date, '%m-%d') <= date_format(start_date, '%m-%d') and
       date_format(@date, '%m-%d') >= date_format(end_date, '%m-%d') 
      );
```

The strings are fine for comparison, because you are only looking at the month and day components of the date.

Given the nature of your problem, I would recommend that you store `start_date` and `end_date` in a non-date format, such as MM-DD.

Comment: @SagarGangwal . . . Comparing strings is fine, if that is the intention of the code.  In this case, with no year component, converting to a date seems a much, much, much worse solution.

Comment: @SagarGangwal . . . You seem very poorly informed.  This code converts the dates to strings in the MM-DD format.  The comparisons are correct.  You will note that the date parts are formatted with leading zeroes, which is why they are correct.  Do you know what MM-DD is?  Do yo know what `'%m-%d'` does in MySQL?  And, as for the example in your comment, it is correct to return 1, because November 11th is "bigger" than January 12th.

Comment: @SagarGangwal . . . I am cutting off this discussion.  You clearly do not know the difference between dates and strings and hence do not understand this logic, even after it has been explained both in the answer itself and in the comments.

Comment: @SagarGangwal: Yep, you're totally wrong, of course `11-11` (=November 11)  is greater than `01-12` (January 12) because you compare `MM-DD` instead of `DD-MM`.

Comment: Well, I finally went with @GordonLinoff answer. I had problems in periods of time like 12-01 to 31-01, comparing which of the dates was greater than the other. Finally, I've modified the data to not include periods of time where the startDate belongs to a different "year" than the endDate. I also converted all the period dates to string, and removed the year on them.

Comment: @SagarGangwal: Of course, but there's no need to add another function :)